# Get the number of parameters of a linear model

Tags: r, regression

Is there a way to get the number of parameters of a linear model like that?

```
model <- lm(Y~X1+X2)
```

I would like to get the number 3 somehow (intercept + X1 + X2). I looked for something like this in the structures that `lm`, `summary(model)` and `anova(model)` return, but I didn't figure it out. In case I don't get an answer, I'll stick on

```
dim(model.matrix(model))[2]
```

Thank you

Comment: The function `attibutes(loglik(obj))` is working fine. The reason why it gives a number larger in 1 unit to the value is because you have to estimate the mean value of the model without any covariate. The mean of the model, let's say. So it is working perfect.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like:

```
> x <- replicate(2, rnorm(100))
> y <- 1.2*x[,1]+rnorm(100)
> summary(lm.fit <- lm(y~x))
> length(lm.fit$coefficients)
[1] 3
> # or
> length(coef(lm.fit))
[1] 3
```

You can have a better idea of what an R object includes with

```
> str(lm.fit)
```

Comment: Thank you. In the meanwhile I realized that I also need the number of observations (n). One way is this: dim(model.matrix(model))[1] Can you suggest another way ?

Comment: @Brani Try `nrow(na.omit(cbind(y,x1,x2)))` (following your notation) or `length(lm.fit$model$y)`, to get the number of observations used when estimating model parameters. BTW, you're better off making a data.frame, e.g. `df <- data.frame(y,x1,x2)`, and then use `lm(y ~ ., data=df)`.

Answer (score 5):

A more general approach is to use the `logLik()` function.  It returns an object with the attribute `df` that gives the fitted models degrees of freedom.  The benefit of this approach is that it works with many other model classes (including `glm`).  In the case of ordinary linear regression (`lm`) this corresponds to the number of parameters + 1 for the  estimate of the error variance.

From the `logLik` documentation:

> For "lm" fits it is assumed that the scale has been estimated (by maximum likelihood or REML), and all the constants in the log-likelihood are included.

You can get the number of observations this way too.

```
> X1 <- rnorm(10)
> X2 <- rnorm(10)
> Y <- X1 + X2 + rnorm(10)
> model <- lm(Y~X1+X2)
> ll <- logLik(model)
> attributes(ll)
$nall
[1] 10

$nobs
[1] 10

$df
[1] 4

$class
[1] "logLik"
```

Answer (score 3):

May be it's a little bit hackish but you can do :

```
n <- length(coefficients(model))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use the component `lm.fit$rank` or else subtract `lm.fit$df.residual` from the sample size to get what you want. (I assume you want the number of free parameters.)

Answer (score 0):

The R function `logLik` seems to be an attractive solution to extract model degree of freedom in general, since it can be applied to many model objects including `lm`, `glm`, `nls`, `Arima` to name a few.

But the `df` of `attributes(logLik(obj))` seems to be 1 larger than the true value. So use it with caution.

Comment: can you explain why you think it's one larger than it should be? Do you have a simple example you could show? (Are you ignoring the existence of a variance parameter, perhaps?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution if your model is nls, with an example dataset in r:

```
# Fit a nls model (this is a light response curve of photosynthesis, in this case)
mod<-nls(response~(alpha*x+Pm-sqrt(((alpha*x+Pm)^2)-4*alpha*x*Pm*theta))/(2*theta)+Rd, data = Data, start=list(alpha=0.05, theta=0.5, Rd=-1, Pm=30))

# There are four parameters, Pm, alpha, theta and Rd.
length(mod$m$getPars())
```

As @Sam pointed out, logLik gives the number of parameters +1.

```
attributes(logLik(mod))$df
```

Here is the example dataset, so you can reproduce the commands above.

```
Data<-structure(list(x = c(-8, -3.97194388777555, 0.0561122244488974, 4.08416833667335, 8.11222444889779, 12.1402805611222, 16.1683366733467, 20.1963927855711, 24.2244488977956, 28.25250501002, 32.2805611222445, 36.3086172344689, 40.3366733466934, 44.3647294589178, 48.3927855711423, 52.4208416833667, 56.4488977955912, 60.4769539078156, 64.5050100200401, 68.5330661322645, 72.561122244489, 76.5891783567134, 80.6172344689379, 84.6452905811623, 88.6733466933868, 92.7014028056112, 96.7294589178357, 100.75751503006, 104.785571142285, 108.813627254509, 112.841683366733, 116.869739478958, 120.897795591182, 124.925851703407, 128.953907815631, 132.981963927856, 137.01002004008, 141.038076152305, 145.066132264529, 149.094188376753, 153.122244488978, 157.150300601202, 161.178356713427, 165.206412825651, 169.234468937876, 173.2625250501, 177.290581162325, 181.318637274549, 185.346693386774, 189.374749498998, 193.402805611222, 197.430861723447, 201.458917835671, 205.486973947896, 209.51503006012, 213.543086172345, 217.571142284569, 221.599198396794, 225.627254509018, 229.655310621242, 233.683366733467, 237.711422845691, 241.739478957916, 245.76753507014, 249.795591182365, 253.823647294589, 257.851703406814, 261.879759519038, 265.907815631263, 269.935871743487, 273.963927855711, 277.991983967936, 282.02004008016, 286.048096192385, 290.076152304609, 294.104208416834, 298.132264529058, 302.160320641283, 306.188376753507, 310.216432865731, 314.244488977956, 318.27254509018, 322.300601202405, 326.328657314629, 330.356713426854, 334.384769539078, 338.412825651303, 342.440881763527, 346.468937875751, 350.496993987976, 354.5250501002, 358.553106212425, 362.581162324649, 366.609218436874, 370.637274549098, 374.665330661323, 378.693386773547, 382.721442885772, 386.749498997996, 390.77755511022, 394.805611222445, 398.833667334669, 402.861723446894, 406.889779559118, 410.917835671343, 414.945891783567, 418.973947895792, 423.002004008016, 427.03006012024, 431.058116232465, 435.086172344689, 439.114228456914, 443.142284569138, 447.170340681363, 451.198396793587, 455.226452905812, 459.254509018036, 463.28256513026, 467.310621242485, 471.338677354709, 475.366733466934, 479.394789579158, 483.422845691383, 487.450901803607, 491.478957915832, 495.507014028056, 499.535070140281, 503.563126252505, 507.591182364729, 511.619238476954, 515.647294589178, 519.675350701403, 523.703406813627, 527.731462925852, 531.759519038076, 535.787575150301, 539.815631262525, 543.843687374749, 547.871743486974, 551.899799599198, 555.927855711423, 559.955911823647, 563.983967935872, 568.012024048096, 572.040080160321, 576.068136272545, 580.09619238477, 584.124248496994, 588.152304609218, 592.180360721443, 596.208416833667, 600.236472945892, 604.264529058116, 608.292585170341, 612.320641282565, 616.348697394789, 620.376753507014, 624.404809619238, 628.432865731463, 632.460921843687, 636.488977955912, 640.517034068136, 644.545090180361, 648.573146292585, 652.60120240481, 656.629258517034, 660.657314629259, 664.685370741483, 668.713426853707, 672.741482965932, 676.769539078156, 680.797595190381, 684.825651302605, 688.85370741483, 692.881763527054, 696.909819639279, 700.937875751503, 704.965931863727, 708.993987975952, 713.022044088176, 717.050100200401, 721.078156312625, 725.10621242485, 729.134268537074, 733.162324649299, 737.190380761523, 741.218436873747, 745.246492985972, 749.274549098196, 753.302605210421, 757.330661322645, 761.35871743487, 765.386773547094, 769.414829659319, 773.442885771543, 777.470941883768, 781.498997995992, 785.527054108216, 789.555110220441, 793.583166332665, 797.61122244489, 801.639278557114, 805.667334669339, 809.695390781563, 813.723446893788, 817.751503006012, 821.779559118236, 825.807615230461, 829.835671342685, 833.86372745491, 837.891783567134, 841.919839679359, 845.947895791583, 849.975951903808, 854.004008016032, 858.032064128256, 862.060120240481, 866.088176352705, 870.11623246493, 874.144288577154, 878.172344689379, 882.200400801603, 886.228456913828, 890.256513026052, 894.284569138277, 898.312625250501, 902.340681362725, 906.36873747495, 910.396793587174, 914.424849699399, 918.452905811623, 922.480961923848, 926.509018036072, 930.537074148297, 934.565130260521, 938.593186372745, 942.62124248497, 946.649298597194, 950.677354709419, 954.705410821643, 958.733466933868, 962.761523046092, 966.789579158317, 970.817635270541, 974.845691382765, 978.87374749499, 982.901803607214, 986.929859719439, 990.957915831663, 994.985971943888, 999.014028056112, 1003.04208416834, 1007.07014028056, 1011.09819639279, 1015.12625250501, 1019.15430861723, 1023.18236472946, 1027.21042084168, 1031.23847695391, 1035.26653306613, 1039.29458917836, 1043.32264529058, 1047.35070140281, 1051.37875751503, 1055.40681362725, 1059.43486973948, 1063.4629258517, 1067.49098196393, 1071.51903807615, 1075.54709418838, 1079.5751503006, 1083.60320641283, 1087.63126252505, 1091.65931863727, 1095.6873747495, 1099.71543086172, 1103.74348697395, 1107.77154308617, 1111.7995991984, 1115.82765531062, 1119.85571142285, 1123.88376753507, 1127.91182364729, 1131.93987975952, 1135.96793587174, 1139.99599198397, 1144.02404809619, 1148.05210420842, 1152.08016032064, 1156.10821643287, 1160.13627254509, 1164.16432865731, 1168.19238476954, 1172.22044088176, 1176.24849699399, 1180.27655310621, 1184.30460921844, 1188.33266533066, 1192.36072144289, 1196.38877755511, 1200.41683366733, 1204.44488977956, 1208.47294589178, 1212.50100200401, 1216.52905811623, 1220.55711422846, 1224.58517034068, 1228.61322645291, 1232.64128256513, 1236.66933867735, 1240.69739478958, 1244.7254509018, 1248.75350701403, 1252.78156312625, 1256.80961923848, 1260.8376753507, 1264.86573146293, 1268.89378757515, 1272.92184368737, 1276.9498997996, 1280.97795591182, 1285.00601202405, 1289.03406813627, 1293.0621242485, 1297.09018036072, 1301.11823647295, 1305.14629258517, 1309.17434869739, 1313.20240480962, 1317.23046092184, 1321.25851703407, 1325.28657314629, 1329.31462925852, 1333.34268537074, 1337.37074148297, 1341.39879759519, 1345.42685370741, 1349.45490981964, 1353.48296593186, 1357.51102204409, 1361.53907815631, 1365.56713426854, 1369.59519038076, 1373.62324649299, 1377.65130260521, 1381.67935871743, 1385.70741482966, 1389.73547094188, 1393.76352705411, 1397.79158316633, 1401.81963927856, 1405.84769539078, 1409.87575150301, 1413.90380761523, 1417.93186372745, 1421.95991983968, 1425.9879759519, 1430.01603206413, 1434.04408817635, 1438.07214428858, 1442.1002004008, 1446.12825651303, 1450.15631262525, 1454.18436873747, 1458.2124248497, 1462.24048096192, 1466.26853707415, 1470.29659318637, 1474.3246492986, 1478.35270541082, 1482.38076152305, 1486.40881763527, 1490.43687374749, 1494.46492985972, 1498.49298597194,1502.52104208417, 1506.54909819639, 1510.57715430862, 1514.60521042084, 1518.63326653307, 1522.66132264529, 1526.68937875751, 1530.71743486974, 1534.74549098196, 1538.77354709419, 1542.80160320641, 1546.82965931864, 1550.85771543086, 1554.88577154309, 1558.91382765531, 1562.94188376754, 1566.96993987976, 1570.99799599198, 1575.02605210421, 1579.05410821643, 1583.08216432866, 1587.11022044088, 1591.13827655311, 1595.16633266533, 1599.19438877756, 1603.22244488978, 1607.250501002, 1611.27855711423, 1615.30661322645, 1619.33466933868, 1623.3627254509, 1627.39078156313, 1631.41883767535, 1635.44689378758, 1639.4749498998, 1643.50300601202, 1647.53106212425, 1651.55911823647, 1655.5871743487, 1659.61523046092, 1663.64328657315, 1667.67134268537, 1671.6993987976, 1675.72745490982,
```

1679.75551102204, 1683.78356713427, 1687.81162324649, 1691.83967935872, 
1695.86773547094, 1699.89579158317, 1703.92384769539, 1707.95190380762, 
1711.97995991984, 1716.00801603206, 1720.03607214429, 1724.06412825651, 
1728.09218436874, 1732.12024048096, 1736.14829659319, 1740.17635270541, 
1744.20440881764, 1748.23246492986, 1752.26052104208, 1756.28857715431, 
1760.31663326653, 1764.34468937876, 1768.37274549098, 1772.40080160321, 
1776.42885771543, 1780.45691382766, 1784.48496993988, 1788.5130260521, 
1792.54108216433, 1796.56913827655, 1800.59719438878, 1804.625250501, 
1808.65330661323, 1812.68136272545, 1816.70941883768, 1820.7374749499, 
1824.76553106212, 1828.79358717435, 1832.82164328657, 1836.8496993988, 
1840.87775551102, 1844.90581162325, 1848.93386773547, 1852.9619238477, 
1856.98997995992, 1861.01803607214, 1865.04609218437, 1869.07414829659, 
1873.10220440882, 1877.13026052104, 1881.15831663327, 1885.18637274549, 
1889.21442885772, 1893.24248496994, 1897.27054108216, 1901.29859719439, 
1905.32665330661, 1909.35470941884, 1913.38276553106, 1917.41082164329, 
1921.43887775551, 1925.46693386774, 1929.49498997996, 1933.52304609218, 
1937.55110220441, 1941.57915831663, 1945.60721442886, 1949.63527054108, 
1953.66332665331, 1957.69138276553, 1961.71943887776, 1965.74749498998, 
1969.7755511022, 1973.80360721443, 1977.83166332665, 1981.85971943888, 
1985.8877755511, 1989.91583166333, 1993.94388777555, 1997.97194388778, 
2002), response = c(-3.58957478518253, -3.62025086478834, -1.04832718629931, 
-0.932815570713867, -2.0059547584204, -1.80378256401687, -1.07078839210859, 
-1.47563839178252, 0.172463665814555, -0.247936953593207, -0.547987522372114, 
-0.942197740134927, -0.173128438044605, -1.07747254510461, 1.10668446828936, 
1.05530666799013, 0.777604622119702, 1.06274622733744, 0.900238206583803, 
1.31412394039238, 1.89499625411371, 1.04033412499542, 1.38191631121636, 
0.999431819175433, 2.68812421375804, 1.47394328081264, 2.72714724358873, 
1.71016394833754, 0.81098268882713, 4.46594845284442, 3.61870598680648, 
3.79687265260293, 3.3731838954602, 1.43858183778185, 2.61595066682473, 
3.76691451510184, 3.13442724430605, 3.10293620326479, 4.45945367139878, 
3.76865197544365, 3.65420270503196, 4.08016861916108, 4.67570693185897, 
5.00811845024315, 5.6912658729918, 6.48591088940087, 4.50595287440596, 
6.43194883116461, 5.21375289859846, 6.06886948554962, 5.85835327159824, 
4.9625308106984, 4.89022500473493, 7.12834025120892, 6.94879254991973, 
6.21082185779307, 7.62504959939155, 6.23255482453099, 6.6760218279274, 
8.20691580592652, 7.57507394269, 6.06526163497662, 8.75382401626834, 
5.70620745514469, 7.26383229655605, 7.46498556138395, 8.7515167860644, 
7.91466462562348, 7.58703158895482, 9.11188767524796, 8.4186401599397, 
6.89096958793887, 7.89158602926514, 10.4612794167006, 7.58318779363375, 
9.84544304325303, 10.6353526028036, 9.19575959965921, 9.83902692183846, 
9.37218617742756, 11.2655524091541, 10.0589316149929, 8.61325152269854, 
10.5773880802015, 10.5060419723174, 11.0722463547765, 10.3359011103665, 
10.026378680973, 11.0063599845354, 11.0079405342041, 10.5867493518446, 
10.8943760523027, 12.1443513080492, 11.8396074471423, 10.3124495936648, 
13.9727593750822, 10.7840244636707, 12.1751132761597, 10.0114338279253, 
12.7398881495442, 11.3496328681914, 12.7336858883009, 11.0014003683233, 
12.6329145237188, 12.8418626240243, 11.3677960547355, 11.5889466372296, 
12.0209030882168, 12.2848054559541, 12.6322237596396, 11.3575397626941, 
13.0492956855345, 13.6665727062986, 12.2082939516701, 13.0091518201203, 
14.3681537231903, 12.4880551714586, 13.5355568479074, 15.6635883385552, 
12.8784669688002, 13.8963858223423, 12.8161474815643, 13.6667437747109, 
12.8263133597971, 14.7562225192782, 13.1809926403271, 14.0891781138646, 
12.5346214636793, 14.1004036308871, 15.8435075654244, 14.358625443445, 
15.8909481383511, 14.4402749451377, 14.1360376888721, 13.3905410466758, 
14.7537155862745, 14.4835085007599, 14.1315006601281, 14.4150998388548, 
15.6952736181339, 13.6437863278995, 17.2083398797518, 14.9719864616975, 
16.8432168022786, 15.1937342978635, 15.1806060147844, 16.3096405343474, 
16.3108213264068, 14.4242808390335, 15.8595948000895, 15.5877173710543, 
15.5005730489912, 17.375526668469, 15.5740671948281, 16.1243289084692, 
15.9749299593302, 17.4147022645292, 18.3700381963525, 13.8143770413523, 
17.9351262044202, 16.7714876710299, 17.0384639772996, 17.0307757081918, 
15.6030920144074, 16.581042152256, 18.8792908358865, 17.998114032928, 
19.1840884966728, 17.1930308829494, 18.9704837093962, 17.5398954859783, 
15.6751901660724, 17.7071141172369, 16.8992272557539, 16.2076829263534, 
16.5355407990975, 17.4297211354828, 17.1911852119539, 17.2638441341946, 
18.7667030206444, 16.9370746309351, 18.1716182139223, 17.6984658296715, 
17.8432253646, 18.6164049373694, 19.4441317654593, 19.0489224386334, 
16.3878174080612, 18.0512428503099, 19.1803487982935, 17.7734002014158, 
20.131130771463, 16.151222737491, 19.0662238624346, 18.9637572654357, 
20.4006961448895, 17.7452159814725, 18.1767897518064, 19.6895978265634, 
17.2415335849138, 19.205432003556, 20.9033294515514, 16.61019386946, 
18.6486223450292, 19.3495539638913, 17.763309794548, 18.589914109576, 
21.3750173075524, 19.0790221140521, 19.073590595151, 20.3110876727817, 
19.1894218140841, 20.2372395516702, 19.1312943191063, 17.8507423410755, 
19.9857184946213, 18.3289008834065, 16.564668684551, 17.2726209464131, 
20.0768841859564, 19.7105832275701, 20.959237751695, 20.6413358795587, 
19.3538018851944, 19.3803009186455, 18.9965213444349, 19.9312882190988, 
20.2498165546154, 20.6602172892069, 19.6600862738064, 20.7052435265234, 
19.7988958134332, 19.369849065903, 20.7005328602028, 21.3901352510254, 
19.9494464318285, 18.5158234507894, 21.0145796229888, 20.3935414006186, 
20.228895878692, 19.4396050963157, 18.9481819487733, 21.8170718923232, 
22.6484071413006, 19.404428374176, 19.574407890811, 19.4134174307073, 
22.6210955210436, 18.7184436222435, 20.5595496522691, 21.6974872718944, 
20.9363644838996, 21.0687129490903, 21.0730189950955, 22.9666927093666, 
22.0189027581993, 22.1601832780259, 20.168790844715, 20.4220194493454, 
20.9451564541633, 20.1454319823462, 22.4361464351762, 20.6198647651334, 
21.4646217438031, 20.5212888882417, 21.3233246747502, 20.7726040755242, 
21.3588194110876, 22.7473931004582, 21.7283608509904, 21.9963790126902, 
21.3213711223197, 22.5202653835615, 22.6692559419185, 22.9911437265527, 
21.0362741019696, 21.2546278761312, 21.664584144617, 22.7666620244984, 
20.256702413919, 23.6864315079695, 25.1766563370701, 21.4323283908586, 
22.2962186929496, 20.3888136631929, 21.9484525615365, 20.7708407269101, 
22.0665761310048, 20.8305234503782, 23.3305723015105, 22.2899098775578, 
22.9720194868776, 22.5367848999167, 21.6382285092653, 22.6582172780793, 
22.1156796214891, 24.2288369587372, 24.380280200404, 23.2915320073326, 
22.3614159703802, 23.6251133797724, 24.1562618798916, 22.9911339744999, 
21.7891891596172, 24.2161382746419, 23.1962083357621, 22.0959042015395, 
22.8241885064288, 23.3231637970656, 24.0340390959745, 23.5064604248494, 
22.4648350821346, 23.8485522024163, 24.6314343012963, 22.9591922937084, 
24.5796619452326, 25.2338435690998, 22.0696906772769, 23.6679180689824, 
22.5138604024011, 23.62164299563, 22.3916895742358, 23.0102593680772, 
24.6826004252832, 21.8474956782121, 23.5836084839005, 23.6096237989221, 
24.0581957504008, 22.7617053199355, 23.7904812246471, 23.8525951859381, 
23.7702560619677, 23.6740561490702, 23.6727772337761, 23.5782892540828, 
24.8012234487132, 22.0448723900358, 26.2446733566806, 24.8901137698615, 
22.4107383673891, 22.3840252340722, 24.8813300530568, 22.8290655247652, 
23.6816776347442, 23.862147975553, 24.9440352220054, 25.602724064874, 
23.4397180626159, 25.2979283706869, 24.0699252609402, 23.8621362261058, 
24.8933828032982, 25.4178762176794, 24.0836079308251, 25.3557779622394, 
26.3252940303689, 22.0335051185389, 24.0425149395311, 23.7462684205931, 
24.6982077315874, 25.3143328826626, 24.6013450624622, 24.7563487352452, 
25.9257328576421, 25.179000436827, 25.8003241661114, 25.0022285204079, 
24.9192596758005, 25.8822418156569, 25.1998009463868, 23.6441535434575, 
24.9426082712576, 24.9539001217398, 22.4577044619626, 23.0437260725105, 
25.9689982595835, 25.9549342010041, 24.5707096652445, 25.6550469220972, 
25.2431319260493, 23.7512180651784, 22.9751208621517, 25.3155008103098, 
25.0914281968248, 24.1433425470407, 25.6845257893322, 25.207267799716, 
24.3853301121691, 25.133367186717, 25.0426003422979, 24.9313250719437, 
25.8037876224851, 25.4260286817899, 26.3335050818361, 24.9988357868418, 
26.7810824981553, 24.6721890010742, 25.4994779162627, 28.2205742456111, 
25.6593981734269, 26.8141269785953, 24.325998577855, 26.772250209721, 
26.6486130860901, 25.2148338608099, 24.435128109376, 25.5111215965461, 
24.7745034027075, 24.7478101468244, 24.9726113562946, 24.2103141988101, 
26.6316537321719, 25.3866804819055, 25.2535960824473, 24.9324610909463, 
26.4330171406269, 24.9555194105079, 24.8680345245781, 27.314004407881, 
25.8497922647969, 25.4365960643182, 27.0640153839225, 26.4115799971681, 
24.5066151411807, 24.0770545981929, 24.5770973417194, 25.6158328694023, 
23.7228591099721, 25.2506608858009, 26.3845249599514, 24.986755107786, 
26.0229796277567, 27.9314117903394, 26.720855107423, 26.2748970068974, 
26.9619543149989, 28.1177017951961, 26.0980959165123, 26.4789358277429, 
27.2640757074367, 27.2474159343653, 25.9992993819392, 26.0604493049298, 
26.6130593710637, 25.7460954198758, 25.4886951704501, 27.249597964836, 
25.8789271815857, 26.1229507075738, 24.0907215160597, 26.4228821021775, 
27.7405264571259, 24.266723432942, 25.0542999074318, 24.1121125081467, 
26.935296245382, 26.4950565230244, 25.4617820698142, 25.0477114029224, 
27.6099550887943, 24.9703729596582, 26.354887191175, 28.5678615888521, 
24.7591852732502, 26.0070564298366, 28.1832364680811, 27.4758598980069, 
25.8492469607027, 25.3129416645233, 26.4844595022583, 27.4346593674058, 
25.0199478369712, 27.4787736031246, 26.6510807143448, 25.9521368094847, 
27.4912196718334, 26.4381208497156, 23.7514049354602, 27.6911406664994, 
25.7380847181156, 27.3970753479465, 25.2686534213865, 26.625449280584, 
27.6915237551073, 28.2585398441531, 25.0055625526628, 28.9395902046147, 
27.1152633304668, 27.4458034523227, 28.4665155499299, 25.7325216430656, 
27.4268908314492, 26.0789361712655, 26.5857269918754, 28.0991123511731, 
28.833576055686, 27.9601071193266, 26.1630868619856, 29.3301360779517, 
28.4273979734602)), .Names = c("x", "response"), row.names = c(NA, 
-500L), class = "data.frame")